# How to hide one remote's commit history from other remotes?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-commit, git-remote

Suppose I've multiple remotes for a single repository. Most of the time I use one git account for the development purpose, and when I'm finished, I push the final version to another remote. Now, how can I hide my commit history of the first remote from the second one?

Answer (score 2):

I'll show you how to do what you asked for, then tell you why this is a bad idea. :-)

History, in any Git repository, is simply the set of *commits* in that repository, as found by the set of *names* in that repository.  This finding process works backwards, because Git always works backwards.  We'll see more on this in a moment.

#### Background

Remember that each *commit* has a unique hash ID.  This is, in effect, the true name of a commit.  To view a commit with `git log`, you must somehow clue Git in to the commit's hash ID.  Git can then retrieve that commit from the repository database, provided it's in the database in the first place.

Every commit has a full snapshot of all of your files—that's the main data in the commit—plus some *metadata:* information about the commit itself, such as who made it, when (date-and-time-stamp), and why (the log message).  Most of this metadata is just stuff Git is to show you with `git log`.  But one crucial piece of information in the metadata, needed by Git itself, is in here too.  Every commit has a list of the raw hash IDs of its *parent* commits.  Most commits have just one entry in this list, as they have a single parent.

This hash ID means that if we somehow find some *starting* commit hash `H`, we can get the commit itself and show it, and use it to find its parent (earlier) commit.  Let's call that commit `G`.  We say that commit `H` *points to* commit `G`:

```
      ... G <-H
```

But G also *points to* an earlier commit—let's call it `F`—like this:

```
  ... F <-G <-H
```

and of course `F` points backwards too:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

So all we really need is a way to tell Git: *the **last** commit's hash ID is _____* (fill in the blank with a hash ID).

This is what a branch name is and does: it provides the *last* commit's hash ID.  The branch name *points to* a commit, just as each commit points to an earlier commit.  This way, we don't have to remember big ugly hash IDs that humans can't deal with.  We only have to remember branch names.  The *names* remember the big ugly hash IDs:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

> ... when I'm finished [making new commits] ...

Let's look at the process of making a new commit.  Let's make a *new* branch name, `feature` for instance, right now.  The branch name *has to point to some existing commit*—that's the rules in Git: a branch name points to some commit.  Of the `...--F--G--H` series, the obvious one to use is ... the last one:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), master
```

We need a way to remember which *branch name* we're using, so I've attached the special name `HEAD` to the new name `feature`.  This is what we get if we do:

```
git checkout -b feature master
```

We're still working with commit `H`, but now we're `on branch feature`, as `git status` will say.  The special name `HEAD` is attached to `feature` now, instead of `master`.

When we make a new commit, it gets a new, never-used-where-else-before, never-to-be-used-anywhere-else-ever-again commit hash `I`.  New commit `I` points back to existing commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Repeat a few times and you have this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Eventually, you're done making commits.  You can now `git push` to some remote, such as `origin`.  The way this works is that your Git calls up another Git—the one at the URL stored under the remote name, `origin`—and *offers them some commit(s) by hash ID*.

They look in *their* repository to see if they have that hash ID.  If you offer them commit `K`, they won't have it.  That forces your Git to offer them commit `J` too, because `J` is `K`'s parent, and that, too, is part of the rules of Git.  They won't have that, so your Git will offer `I`, and they won't have that so your Git will offer `H`.  Here, they might well have `H`!  Let's say they do.  This lets your Git stop offering hash IDs.

Now your Git has to package up the new-to-them commits, `I-J-K`, and send them.  You'll see messages about counting and compressing here, and then your Git sends the commits across.

The `git push` now enters its final phase: it sends them a polite request: *If it's OK, please set your branch name ______ to point to commit `K`.*  As long as this *adds* commits to one of their branches, without removing any commits from that branch, they are likely to obey this request.  If it's a totally new branch name, they are even more likely to obey this request.

The end result is that now *they* have *their* branch name pointing to the last commit `K` in the chain of commits.  From `K`, they'll find `J`, then `I`, and then `H`, and so on.  **This is the history they have in their repository now.**

#### What you want

> ... how can I hide my commit history of the first remote from the second one?

You can't, or, not exactly.  You can, however, make *new* commit(s) that *are a different history*, and send those *instead*.

Suppose you, in your own repository, make a new and different branch name, using:

```
git checkout -b other-guy master
```

This gives you, in your Git repository, this series of names and commits:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, other-guy (HEAD)
            \
             I--J--K   <-- feature
```

Your current *commit* is now commit `H`.  Your current *branch name* is now `other-guy`.

You can now make a *new* commit—with a totally new, never-seen-before hash ID, which we'll call `L`—with whatever snapshot in it you like.  Let's not worry about *how* you do that yet and just draw the result:

```
             L   <-- other-guy (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- feature
```

You can now use:

```
git push other-remote other-guy:feature
```

This has your Git call up the Git stored under the remote name `other-remote` and offer them commit `L`.  They won't have it, so your Git will also offer commit `H`.  They might have that one—it's been going around for a while—so your Git can probably stop there, bundle up `L`, and send it over.

Now your Git sends their Git a polite request of the form: *If it's OK, please set or create your name `feature` pointing to commit `L`.*  If they accept, what *they* have in *their* repository is:

```
...--H--L   <-- feature
```

(they probably have some other name, such as their `master`, pointing to `H`, we just didn't draw it here).  So *their* commits in *their* repository are found by starting from their name `feature`, which identifies commit `L`.  They'll show commit `L`.  Then they'll move back to `L`'s parent `H`, and show `H`, and so on.

Note how they never show `I-J-K`.  They *can't*, because they *don't have them*.  They can, now or in the future, if they want and have access, get them from you and/or from any other Git you sent them to, or any Git that has Git-sex with the Git you sent them to and thereby picks them up, and so on; but right now, they aren't infected with commits `I-J-K`.

(Gits in general really like to pick up new commits.  Gits in general do not like to give up commits.  It's very easy to spread commits around like infections.)

#### The easy way to make commit `L`

I promised to show you how to do what you want.  There's an easy way to make commit `L` after making `I-J-K`, and that's to use `git merge --squash`.

Given this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, other-guy (HEAD)
            \
             I--J--K   <-- feature
```

you can run `git merge --squash feature` and then `git commit`.  The `git merge --squash` tells Git: *Do everything you would for a real merge, but then stop without committing.  When I make the commit, make it as a regular everyday single-parent commit, not a merge commit with its two parents.*

Git now combines the difference from commit `H` to commit `H`—no change at all—with the difference from `H` to `K`, and applies all those changes to the snapshot in `H`, resulting in the snapshot in `K`.  This snapshot isn't *committed* yet, but you run `git commit`, fill in the commit message however you like, and now it is:

```
             L   <-- other-guy (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- feature
```

and you're ready to `git push` commit `L` and have someone else call it `feature`.

#### Why you probably shouldn't do this

As soon as you've done this once, your next starting position in your own repository is this:

```
             L   <-- other-guy (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- feature
```

One of your two remotes has this same setup except that it lacks commit `L` entirely.  If you want to send commit `L` there, you'll need to use some name other than `feature` this time: their name `feature` remembers commit `K`.  You can tell them to forcibly drop `I-J-K` in favor of `L`, but if you do that, you've already given up on doing what you asked for: now both other remotes *only* can find commit `L` (at least, via their name `feature`).

If you want to develop more stuff, you now have a problem: do you start from commit `K`, or do you start from commit `L`?  If you start from `L`, your own history for the new work you do, does not have the `I-J-K` history.  History, after all, is *the set of commits as found by some name and working backwards*.

So what you end up doing is one of two things:

- make a lot of histories you ignore (your own `feature` branches, that you abandon by starting the next one from commit `L` in this case), or
- start having to do `git merge --squash` when you did a `git merge --squash`.

Let's see how the latter works:

```
git checkout feature
```

now results in:

```
             L   <-- other-guy
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

We make more commits:

```
             L   <-- other-guy
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--M--N   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Now we go to squash-merge:

```
git checkout other-guy
git merge --squash feature
```

This merges work—as in, compares `H` vs `L` to find "our" changes, and `H` vs `N` to find "their" changes, and combines the changes.  This often works OK ... but if anything we did in `M-N` *un-does* something in `I-J-K`, or touches the same *lines* as something we did in `I-J-K`, we get a *merge conflict*.

There are ways to deal with this, and in the end we get:

```
             L--O   <-- other-guy
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--M--N   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

where `O` has the squashed result of combining `M` and `N`.  You can now `git push` the two different histories to two different places.

This really *can* work.  It just gets to be painful over time.  There's also that other "infection-like" problem: you've sent commits `I-J-K-M-N` to some other Git.  Chances are pretty good that those commits will get spread into more Git clones, and from there, will get to the clone you were trying to keep these secret from.  Even if this doesn't happen, it's really easy to goof up on your own end, by doing `git push other-guy feature` (though fortunately after the first round, this will normally get rejected as a "not a fast-forward" error).

In short, secrets—the hidden commits—generally just don't last once shared.  There's usually a much simpler alternative.  I don't know your motive for wanting all of this, though, so it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation :)

Comment: but then why if I `git merge --squash otherguy/branch` and then `commit -m my commit` I get the `otherguy` remote name next to the commit hash like so `commit fa5d2c467a6a08de77bd608f69f4a1c2d1e0586d6 (origin/develop, coordination/develop, develop)`

Comment: @dnuske: `git merge --squash` makes an ordinary commit (i.e., a commit with one parent), with author and committer set as usual for any ordinary commit (i.e., based on your user.name and user.email unless overridden), on the current branch. If the current branch is `develop`, the new commit should at this point *only* be on `develop`. Once you `git push origin develop`, however, and they accept it, `origin/develop` in your repository will update, so you'll see that—or if you `git push coordination develop` you'll see *that*. If `origin` then reset their `develop`, [continued]

Comment: If `origin` (or respectively `coordination`) reset *their* `develop` branch and you `git fetch` from that remote, that will update your local `origin/develop` (or `coordination/develop`) name, so that `git log` will now show all three names as identfying this new commit. Remember that `git log` simply shows the state of *your* repository; it's `git fetch` and `git push` that *update the state of your repository* according to what your Git sees happening in some other repository *at that time*.

Comment: If you're seeing `origin/develop` and `coordination/develop` update *immediately* (without running `git push` or `git fetch`), then something else—it's not clear what—is running `git push` and/or `git fetch` and/or lying to your Git software. If you're using a GUI, perhaps the GUI is auto-pushing-and-fetching as a fancy instant synchronization feature.